# How to load an HTML5 document that is part of the project?

Tags: ios, xcode

i am working on an iPhone app, in my project I added an HTML5 page that is a template, and have a webview and want to load it on viewdidload. I can't seem to be able to access it, I am trying this :

```
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(    NSAllApplicationsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES ) ;

NSString *documentDirectory =  [ documentDirectories objectAtIndex: 0 ] ;
    NSString *longPath = [ documentDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@" filename ] ;
```

I am a bit confused? How can I achieve this? do I need to tell xcode that this html5 needs to be built and sent to a specific folder at runtime? like treated as a resource?

I am new to xcode coming from a .NET environment, so maybe the terminology is a bit awkward.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your html file in bundle or in document directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's part of the project it won't be in the documents directory it'll be in your application bundle. For example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"html"]];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: The html file is on the same level as the viewcontroller. I am doing the following :

Comment: NSString *fileName = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"sampleHTML.html"  ] ;
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"]];
       NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [self.webView loadRequest:req];

Comment: still nothing, I cannot load the html file, I get an error : [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Got it, I need to use the file name without the extension, so        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleHTML" ofType:@"html" ]];